# Excel Data to Data Grid View in vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

Hi everybody I am new!

So, I was developing a simple software with VB 6.0 (yeah, i know quite old). I had to do is manipulate Ms Excel sheet into VB Application. The actual task is to display the data or tables (whatever we call it)provided in the Excel sheet into Data Grid View.

I am using ADODB. Here is the code:

```
  Dim file_name As String
  Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
 cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
 file_name & ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

 If cn.State = adStateOpen Then
     MsgBox "Excel File is Connected. ", , "Message"
     rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
     rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", cn, 3, 3, 1 - adCmdText
     Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
     DataGrid1.Refresh
     DataGrid1.ReBind

  Else: MsgBox "Error: Excel File is not Connected. ", , "Message"
 End If
 rs.Close
 cn.Close
```

But I am facing a problem! Now the excel data is shown in Data Grid Control. But immediately the data is erased after the execution of the Line "rs.close". I am giving a snapshot.

Please Help. Thank you...

Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: you don't close the recordset and the connection... delete rs.close and cn.close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't close the recordset and the connection... you delete rs.close and cn.close